# MVC 5 Folder Structure Issue When Publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have several pages in a subfolder in the Shared folder.

I render theese as Partial Views on a View page like this:

```
@Html.Partial("Scripts/Case_Action")
@Html.Partial("Scripts/Case_Action_Comments")
@Html.Partial("Scripts/Case_History")
```

When I am debugging this works perfect but when I publish the site it doesn't find the files anymore.

When I debugg the URL looks like this: `http://localhost:44300/Case/id` and when I publish the URL is this: `http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/FOLDER/Case/id` where xxx* is the IP.

So how can I get this work both when I debugg and when I publish?

And here is the error:

```
The partial view 'Scripts/Case_Action' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Case/Scripts/Case_Action.aspx
~/Views/Case/Scripts/Case_Action.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Scripts/Case_Action.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Scripts/Case_Action.ascx
~/Views/Case/Scripts/Case_Action.cshtml
~/Views/Case/Scripts/Case_Action.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Scripts/Case_Action.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Scripts/Case_Action.vbhtml
```

Comment: Try this `@Html.Partial("Scripts/Case_Action_Comments.cshtml")` and in  others also

Comment: @AmitAgrawal what would that do? The view engine obviously attempts to find `.cshtml` files.

Comment: @Stijn: Sometimes it's creating problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views must have the `Content` build action, else they won't be included in a publish. Check the Properties of your views:

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio]

Comment: The View or Partial Views or both?

Comment: @stibay both. A view is not defined as "full" or "partial", a single view can be rendered as both.